# Getting error "Target object of type ...has no eligible methods for handling Messages"

Tags: spring-integration

I am using spring integration in my project. 
I have recently added the below  method for my service activator `PQMessageHandler`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Message<?> getDatabaseProductName(Message<?> inMessage){
        Message<?> outMessage = null;
        String databaseProductName = null;
        try {
            //get the database name. 
            databaseProductName = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(rd).getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        Document mainDom = XmlParserUtil.convertString2Document((String)inMessage.getPayload());
        //include database name in the response xml
        Element databaseName = mainDom.getRootElement().addElement("databaseName");
        databaseName.setText(databaseProductName);
        MessageHeaders inMsgHdrs = inMessage.getHeaders();

        MessageBuilder<?> msgBuilder = MessageBuilder.withPayload(mainDom.asXML()).copyHeaders(inMsgHdrs);
        outMessage= msgBuilder.build();
        logger.debug("\n ************************** External System Request Message ********************* \n");
        logger.debug(outMessage);
        logger.debug("\n ******************************************************************************** \n");

        return outMessage;      

    }
```

I have configured the code that calls the above service activator is as follows:

```
<int:channel id="PQPutUserBAInformation-Add-DatabaseProductName" />
    <int:service-activator input-channel="PQPutUserBAInformation-Add-DatabaseProductName"
                           output-channel="PQPutUserBAInformation-Database-Router"
                           ref="msgHandler" 
                           method="getDatabaseProductName" />

    <int:router input-channel="PQPutUserBAInformation-Database-Router" default-output-channel="PQPutUserBAInformation-Default-InsertUserId-Channel" resolution-required="false" expression="#xpath(payload, '//databaseName').toLowerCase().contains('db2')">
        <int:mapping value="true" channel="PQPutUserBAInformation-DB2-Request"/>
    </int:router>
```

The above code works fine without any issues in the development environment. Weirdly when I deploy my application in client environment, I am getting the following error:

> 2017-04-10 10:41:50,525 INFO  [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
>
> 2017-04-10 10:41:50,526 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#345': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#61' while setting bean property 'handler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#61': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target object of type [class com.dsths.cs.awd.jobs.PQMessageHandler] has no eligible methods for handling Messages.
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329) [spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]

I am assuming that the recent changes are causing the issue. The log message is not clearly saying which service activator is causing the issue.

I googled about the error and confirmed that 
1) There is no misspelled method attribute in the  
configuration
2)The method is public 
3)I haven't defined `requires-reply="true"` attribute in the configuration.

Any thoughts on troubleshooting the issue?

Comment: `#61` means it's the 62nd `<service-activator/>` in the context; it's generally easier to debug such issues by giving all your components an `id` attribute so the parser doesn't have to generate a bean name. Is that `getDatabaseProductName` method in `PQMessageHandler` ? Are you sure there's not another bean `msgHandler` - that seems like a very generic name, given that you have so many service activators.

Comment: Yes, the method `getDatabaseProductName` is in the `PQMessageHandler`. I am sure that there is not another bean `msgHandler`. The weird thing is that the same war file is been deployed without any issues in the dev environment, but it  blew up in the client environment. Is there any possibility that the jar conflicts/version conflicts would throw that error?

Comment: It's hard to say; the code is very straightforward when you explicitly declare the method name in the configuration like that. You might get some more clues if you turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework.integration`, but my guess is you won't. Another possibility is there's an older version of that class on the classpath. Using the `- verbose` JVM command line option will tell you which jar the class is loaded from.

Comment: @Gary Russell, You are correct. Thanks for the support. Figured out the root cause for the issue. The exception was due to EAR caching. Cleaning the EAR folder on Linux server and redeploying the war file freshly has worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the root cause for the issue. The exception was due to EAR caching. Cleaning the EAR folder on Linux server and redeploying the war file freshly has worked out.